# Get the result of a consultation with the SUM function in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to perform a query by cakephp with the sum function, but is not returning me the expected result.

The controller is configured so ;

```
$PedItensOmitens = $PedItenstable->find('all', [
'fields' => array( 'item_prod, sum(item_qtd)as total'),
])->join(['b' =>[
'table' =>'om_itens',
'type' =>'INNER',
'conditions' => 'item_id = b.omi_item'
]
])->where(['b.omi_ordom ' => $ordemMontagem->om_id
])->Group(['item_prod '
]);
```

and this me returning the message " Error : SQLSTATE [ 42000 ] : Syntax error or access violation : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax ; check the manual que Corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' AS PedItens__sum ( item_qtd ) the full FROM ped_itens PedItens INNER JOIN om_itens ' at line 1 "

Making the query in the database with mysql is so

```
select a.item_prod, sum(a.item_qtd)as total from ped_itens a inner join om_itens b on a.item_id = b.omi_item where b.omi_ordom = 1 group b a.item_prod
```

and brings me the expected result

item_prod - total

7 - 2400.00

9 - 5292.00

10 - 6492.00

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try substituting the `fields` array with `->select`.  Something like:

```
$PedItensOmitens = $PedItenstable->find()
    ->select([
        'item_prod' => 'item_prod',
        'total' => 'sum(item_qtd)'
    ])
    ->join([
        'b' =>[
            'table' =>'om_itens',
            'type' =>'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'item_id = b.omi_item'
        ]
    ])
    ->where(['b.omi_ordom ' => $ordemMontagem->om_id])
    ->Group(['item_prod'
]);
```

It is also probably a good idea to specify which tables you are selecting from in the Cake query, similar to what you have in your raw SQL.  So in the select:

```
'item_prod' => 'a.item_prod', // where a is your model alias
'total' => 'sum(a.item_qtd)'
```

Comment: ... and it would be an even better idea to use function expressions http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions